# Recognizing MONTH+YEAR in one column, making a SUM of the corresponding column in EXCEL

Tags: excel, ms-office

I've been working all day to make a proper excel file for my business. I'm almost done but I can't get my head around this one particular issue.

I want the program to make a sum of all cells in column F that have a date that is in January in column C.

So basically column C has dates in it, and column F has currency in it. I'm trying to make a seperate table that sums up montly earnings.

I've tried about everything I know about the IF function but I can't seem to figure it out. I know what I want the program to do, but I don't know how to make it happen.

Thanks in advance,
Marc

Comment: Look into the SUMIFS function, you just need set one criteria to =< first day and the other criteria to => last day of the month.

Comment: @VBAPete Thanks for pointing me into the right direction, I'll look into that.

Comment: No worries, let me know if you need help with setting up the function.

Comment: @VBAPete Am I wrong to assume that "=SUMIFS(F3:F45,C3:C45,=<DATE(2017,1,1),C3:C45,=>DATE(2017,1,31))" should be my solution? Well, I know I am wrong because it doesn't work, but am I getting close? F column is where the currency is at and column C are the dates.

Comment: close: =SUMIFS(F3:F45,C3:C45,">=1/1/2017",C3:C45,"<=1/31/2017")

Comment: @VBAPete Ah, I was actually very close haha. Thanks a lot man, it works! :-)